# Why does Double.ToString("#") and BigInteger.ToString() produce different results for the same value?

Tags: c#, precision, biginteger

Consider the following code:

```cs
double d = double.MaxValue;
BigInteger bi = new(d);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("#"));
Console.WriteLine(bi.ToString());
```

This yields the following result:

```
179769313486232000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368
```

The `BigInteger` representation of this value contains *seemingly* random numbers, whilst the `double` representation contains 294 trailing zeros. Both are the same length.

Why is this, and what are those *seemingly* random numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e05944dd74118db06d6987fe2724813950725737/src/libraries/System.Runtime.Numerics/src/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs#L202) of `BigInteger(double)`, you'll see that the internal representation is stored in an `int[]` in base 2. The value from the double is packed into the last 3 elements of this `_bits` array;

```cs
// Populate the uints.
_bits = new uint[cu + 2];
_bits[cu + 1] = (uint)(man >> (cbit + kcbitUint));
_bits[cu] = unchecked((uint)(man >> cbit));
if (cbit > 0)
    _bits[cu - 1] = unchecked((uint)man) << (kcbitUint - cbit);
_sign = sign;
```

All the other `_bits[0..cu -1]` elements will be initialised to zero. Giving a final value of the form `x * 2^k`, not `x * 10^k`. Any large value of `k` may look like random noise when converted to base 10.

But in base 16, the answer is obvious;

```cs
new BigInteger(double.MaxValue).ToString("X") == "0FFFFFFFFFFFFF800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

It's `double.MaxValue.ToString("#")` that is rounding the significant digits in base 10.